# What are the rules to simplify this equation?

Tags: arithmetic, education

I know that I can these two terms are equal, but I would like to understand **why** the are equal and **what rules** are involved in translating one term in the other. Here are the terms: $$-\frac{ae^{-ax}}{1 + e^{-ax}} = -\frac{a}{1 + e^{ax}}$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: $a$ is a multiplier on both sides, so you could divide both sides by $a$, assuming all values are well defined. Since $a/a=1$ then that multiplicand would cancel. Other tricks can be used, e.g. symbolically multiplying a side, or both sides if you want, by the "number 1 in disguise," e.g. $1=(1-e^{ax})/(1-e^{ax})$, then expanding either the numerator or denominator to get something useful. Or as has been pointed out in one of the answers, multiply by $1=e^{ax}/e^{ax}$. Note - multiplying by "1" may seem pointless, but can symbolically simplify an expression into an equivalent yet simpler form.

Comment: For example, $(1+e^{ax})(1-e^{ax})=1-e^{2ax}$. But I would probably multiply by $e^{ax}/e^{ax}$ and then use hyperbolic trigonometric functions defined via the exponential function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Write

$$-\frac{ae^{-ax}}{1+e^{-ax}}\cdot \frac{e^{ax}}{e^{ax}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try cross-multiplying. Then simplify each side.

Comment: +1 Using cross multiplication is literally the definition of equality between fractions, once you really get into it (although in more general settings you have to allow for fractions to be expanded before cross multiplying, it isn't necessary for integers, or real numbers, or complex numbers, or polynomials, or anything else one might reasonably expect to encounter at high school level).